# VBA - problems with getting html from a website after hitting submit button

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap data out of a section of a webpage. To get into the section I need to fill in a captcha security code and hit a button, but that is alright because the security code is actually written in the html of the page. So, I am creating an IE object, driving it to the webpage, getting the captcha security code, writing it in the proper box, hitting the submit button and then getting the html document so I can scrap data out of it.

Nonetheless I am executing the steps exatcly in the order I mentioned, it seems that the html document that is being gotten is not the one from the page after I pass through the captcha validation, but from the page before the captcha validation.

Would anyone know what must I do to get the correct html document and conseuently be able to scrap the data I really want? Thank you.

The subprocedure's code follows next:

```
'Getting National fuel prices from ANP
Sub subANPNationalFuelPrices()
'Creating variables for the URL and the HTML files
Dim urlANP As String: urlANP = "http://www.anp.gov.br/preco/prc/Resumo_Semanal_Index.asp"
Dim htmlANP1 As HTMLDocument

'Creating the IE object
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True

'Making sure that the webpage is fully load
IE.navigate (urlANP)
Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.StatusBar = "Getting your data"
DoEvents
Loop

Set htmlANP1 = IE.document

'Getting the Captcha Password
Dim strCaptchaPassword As String
Dim colMyCollection As IHTMLElementCollection
Set colMyCollection = htmlANP1.getElementById("divQuadro").all

Dim objLabel As IHTMLElement

For Each objLabel In colMyCollection
strCaptchaPassword = strCaptchaPassword & objLabel.innerText
Next objLabel

'Getting the input box object and getting it the correct password
Dim objInputBox As IHTMLElement
Set objInputBox = htmlANP1.getElementById("txtValor")
objInputBox.Value = strCaptchaPassword

'Getting the submit button object and clicking it
Dim objInputButton As IHTMLElement
Set objInputButton = htmlANP1.getElementById("image1")
objInputButton.Click

'Getting the true rich data HTML
Set htmlANP1 = IE.document

'Extracting the data from the html document
Dim rngValues As range: Set rngValues = Sheet1.range("B17")
Dim strValues(35) As String
Dim dblValues(35) As Double

Dim objElement1 As IHTMLElement
Set objElement1 = htmlANP1.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")(1)

Dim colCollection1 As IHTMLElementCollection
Set colCollection1 = objElement1.all

Dim intTempCount As Integer
Dim objTempElement As IHTMLElement

intTempCount = 32

For Each objTempElement In colCollection1
Sheet1.Cells(intTempCount, 3) = objTempElement.tagName
Sheet1.Cells(intTempCount, 4) = objTempElement.innerText
intTempCount = intTempCount + 1
Next objTempElement
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not waiting for the new webpage to load after clicking the button on the captcha. Either check the ready state of IE again or end you code here be starting a timer which starts your code off again in X seconds AND then checks the ready state of IE and Document.

Comment: Right after the code that hits the submit button I added some code to wait for 10 seconds then loop till READYSTATE is COMPLETE. The problem remains

Comment: Check the contents of IE.document, does it change? Does your IE page actually change? If yes does your website have Frames?

Comment: Hi Darbid. The IE changes, but the html does not. Yes I just realized that there is an IFrame object in the html (is that what you meant by frames?). How to work that out then?

Answer (score 0):

I do scraping on a system using iFrame so using IE.Readystate isn't very reliable. Usually I have to wait for another element to 'exist', but using IsObject(element) hasn't been very reliable either. What I've had to do is use a loop in my main code that calls a function so if I'm waiting for something to load and I know that after the page loads, there's an element with the ID "UserName", then I do this..

...

```
Do Until IsErr(doc, "UserName") = False: Loop
```

...

```
Function IsErr(doc As HTMLDocument, ID As String) As Boolean

IsErr = True

On Error GoTo ExitFunction:

Debug.Print left(doc.getElementById(ID).innerHTML, 1)
IsErr = False
Exit Function

ExitFunction:

End Function
```

I could just do a loop statement that keeps trying to debug it, but that would be a nightmare with the error handling so if you use a separate function for the printing, it can exit the function after the error, then the loop re-initiates the function and it will do this forever until the next element exists.